# condescension and can

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, auxiliary-verbs, contractions

> We can talk about modal auxiliary verbs in terms of such logical notions as ‘permission’ and ‘necessity’ but, this done, we still have to consider ways in which these notions become remoulded by the social and psychological influences of everyday communication between human beings: factors such as motivation, condescension, politeness, tact and irony. Condescension, for example, in the right context makes the can of 'You can go now' (which in logical terms means no more than ‘permission’) into something approaching a command.

(from p.72 of <Meaning and the English Verb (3rd ed.)> by Geoffrey Leech)

1. In this paragraph, can 'the social and psychological influences' be interpreted as the contraction of 'the social influence and the psychological influence'?
2. In this paragraph, what are the exact meanings of 'condescension' and 'in the right context'?
3. Please tell me the example situation where condescension makes the can of 'You can go now' into something approaching a command rather than permission.

Answer (score 0):

SIDE NOTE: To express permission, the word "may" should actually be used.  When I was in school, if we asked: "Teacher, can I go to the bathroom?", the teacher might reply "I don't know, can you?"  This was a mocking indication that we had used the incorrect grammar to request permission.  "Can" references ability or possibility, but is colloquially, and commonly, used to mean permission, even though this is not strictly correct.

Regardless of the word used for the permission, expressed in a dismissive or impatient tone of voice, or at the critical moment in the conversation where its context would be understood as intolerant, saying "You can/may go now" can definitely sound condescending.  It can imply that the speaker no longer desires the presence of the one addressed.

English speakers rely quite heavily on body language and tone of voice to interpret meaning--more so than many other languages might.  When these non-verbal cues seem ambiguous, misunderstandings are commonplace.  In a text-only environment, the reader is left to infer the intent of the speaker based on the context of the exchange, which is prone to mistaken interpretations.

1. "Social and psychological influences" refer to the affect, or emotional aspect that influences one's thinking based on relationships with others and the suggestions of the mind.
2. "Condescension" means looking down on someone, indicating the speaker feels superior to the one addressed; "in the right context" refers, not to a "correct" context, but rather to a "specific" or "particular" context or setting.
3. Suppose you enter a friend's room, and try to talk to him about an idea which you think is great but for which your friend shows no enthusiasm.  In fact, your friend rather dislikes the idea--yet you attempt to be persuasive.  Clearly annoyed, your friend, to put an end to the discussion, finally says: "You can go now."  In this context, you would understand that your friend no longer desires your presence.  It is not merely *permission* to leave, it is a *request* that you leave.  In this sense, "can" can serve as a command.

Comment: I'd tend to disagree with the "side-note".   Can is used for permission in all but the most formal registers of English.

Comment: @Biblasia: <"Social and psychological influences" refer to the affect, or emotional aspect that influences one's thinking based on relationships with others and the suggestions of the mind.> -> Can this be paraphrased as <"Social and psychological influences" refer to the affect, that is, emotional aspect that influences one's thinking which is based on not only relationships with others but also things that the mind implies.>?

Comment: @JamesK Perhaps you are of the generation that followed mine.  They say language evolves: perhaps _devolves_ is sometimes more applicable, as the old grammatical rules are ignored into oblivion.

Comment: @gonjuyi Your rephrasing is close.  I might prefer it this way:  "Social and psychological influences" refer to the affect, that is, _the_ emotional aspect that influences one's thinking _on account of_ not only relationships with others, but also things that the mind _infers_."  If you want to say "implies," I think "suggests" is better.  Look up "imply" versus "infer" and you will see the distinction in meaning between them.  Essentially, is your mind suggesting thoughts to _you_ or is it "reading between the lines" from what others have communicated to you?

Comment: @biblasia: O.K. Then, how abot <"Social and psychological influences" refer to the affect, that is, the emotional aspect that influences someone's thinking on account of not only the mind's reading between the lines from what someone else has communicated to him or her, but also things that the mind puts forward.>?

Comment: @gonjuyi That sounds good.

Comment: @Biblasia: Many thanks for your very helpful answers. But, one more thing, by your definition, the affect = the emotional aspect that influences one's thinking based on relationships with others and the suggestions of the mind?

Comment: @gonjuyi The word "affect", _as a noun_, means "feeling or emotion."  Check your dictionary.  That is how I am using the word.  I consider the "social and psychological influences" to be addressing the emotional or sentimental impact of those influences, and not merely cognitive (thinking) processes.  Social relationships have little cognitive effect, and significant emotional effect--at least, that is how my mind interprets this.  Others may have their own explanations.

Comment: @Biblasia: O.K. Then how about <"Social and psychological influences" refer to the affect(=the emotional aspect) induced by the mind's reading between the lines from what has been communicated to someone by someone else(we can call this reading the social action of the mind) and the mind's suggesting of thoughts(we can call this suggesting the psychological action of the mind), and "Social and psychological influences" influence someone's thinking.>?